# best practice for lucene.net in a asp.net web application

Tags: lucene.net

If can someone point me to some solution/tutorial about this:

1. web site with many writes (many users inserts, update and delete from db)
2. many reads

Should I create indexes for example every hour or to reindex on every ins,del,upd.

Of course that is nice to have users post indexed right away (and removed if he delete it)  but as db will grow and lucene index also what is clever to do?

Whats the cost of opening and reading for example 1GB lucene index for ram,application.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should have a read a those tutorials :

- http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2010/02/26/lucene.net-is-powering-subtext-2.5-search.aspx
- http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/08/31/lucene.net-the-main-concepts.aspx

And look how lucene.net is implemented in subtext :

- http://code.google.com/p/subtext/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2FSubtext.Framework%2FServices%2FSearchEngine

Comment: This is even better as solution but its discounted, somebody with higher knowledge (not me) should make nice project from this, http://sourceforge.net/projects/seekafile/